# Angular object outside method always undefined

Tags: angular

i want to get information through GET-REQUEST but its always undefined.

If i log it inside the method i get all information. Why its outside undefined? I assigned the response to the variable "resercationSettings". So why its always undefined?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It will (likely) be `undefined` when the print in `ngOnInit` runs since `getUsers` is async. You need to have it return a promise or observable so the caller (`ngOnInit`) can wait for it to finish to see the results you're expecting. Also, don't post images of code and output. Always post all information as text.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem. I implemented a promise.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is async and when you do a `console.log()` outside of `subscribe`, the request is not yet finished and it logs undefined.

`userService.getAllUsers()` returns `Observable`, and you basically subscribe to the result of the request. That is why in `subscribe` block, you have the value.